# WPF application with a scrollbar in frame

Tags: wpf, uiscrollview, frame

I'm making a WPF application but i just can't get the scrollbar working

this is my Xaml from the mainpage:

```
        <Border Name="myBorder_FrameRight" BorderBrush="#FF3F0000" BorderThickness="2" Background="#8AFFFFFF" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame MaxHeight="300" Name="myFrame_PagesRight" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Navigated="myFrame_PagesRight_Navigated" 
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
```

I wanna show a page in it with a Height="520"

But the page got cut off at the buttom and it doens't enable the scrollbar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to remove the ScrollViewer.

A Frame has already got a ScrollViewer in it. If you put the Frame in a ScrollViewer, it will have two ScrollViewers. It can be done this way, but then you'll have to configure them both.

EDIT:

Easiest possible:

```
<Border Name="myBorder_FrameRight">
        <Frame MaxHeight="300" Name="myFrame_PagesRight" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</Border>
```

Comment: If i do that I still don't see the scrollbar.

Comment: Then you are probably not showing everything.
Edit: Added an example

Comment: This solution is not working. Voted down.